# How to set different auto-increment ids for two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have 2 tables, both with auto-incremented primary keys and I want the ids to be unique between the two tables - i.e. no two equal values will be used as primary keys for those tables.

To put this into context, I want to do something similar to what facebook is doing with their ID's - sharing them among users, pages, events, etc. Also, I want to ensure I can scale the system in the future.

I have three ideas in mind right now, and can't decide to go with one of them.

1. Incrementing ID's by 10 and starting from different values - i.e. Table A: 1, 11, 21.... & Table B: 2, 12, 22 - This is a bit stupid since you loose lots of ids
2. Using GUIDs - I think I can do better
3. Using unsigned bigint for the id column and starting from 1 with one table and from a sufficiently large number for the other

What's the best way to do it? Or is there another way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a third table called IDs or something similar. That will be the only table with an auto_increment. It will be used only to generate ids so you go something like this:

```
insert into ids (id) values (null);
@id = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into users (id, name) values (@id, "Andreas ");
```

Same goes for all other tables that need an id. You can add a third table at any time.

If you wish you could even keep information in the ids table about what table holds this row.

```
insert into ids (id, table) values (null, "users");
@id = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into users (id, name) values (@id, "Andreas ");
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these are fine.

You can use option 1 without losing any keys by setting the increment to 2 and the starting offset to 1 for the first table and 2 for the second table. Then table 1's IDs will go 1,3,5... and table 2's will go 2,4,6...

3 is basically identical to option 1. Although I don't like the idea of having to keep track of some magic number in my code if I ever needed to differentiate between IDs from each table in my code.

GUIDs are fine too. They are slower and require more storage space but practically you may not notice any difference. And if you don't notice any difference in your application, who cares?

Answer (score 0):

Use GUIDs/[UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)s or some kind of requestUniqueKey stored procedures that maintains its own key table. Unfortunately there is no recommended way how to store a UUID in MySQL as far as I know (like UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in MS SQL Server).